# ¿Por qué no imprime los datos del arreglo bidimensional?

Tags: java, array

Cuando intento imprimir el ejercicio de arreglos bidimensional que estoy practicando no me retorna los datos ingresados en cada celda. He revisado el código varias veces y parece estar bien. ¿Que debo hacer? ¿Por que lo imprime así?

Aquí les dejo el código:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int calificaciones[][]=new int [5][];
    calificaciones [0]=new int [1];
    calificaciones [1]=new int [2];
    calificaciones [2]=new int [3];
    calificaciones [3]=new int [4];
    calificaciones [4]=new int [5];

    for(int[] CalificacionsPorAlumno : calificaciones) 
    {
        for(int calificacion : CalificacionsPorAlumno) 
        {
            System.out.print(calificaciones + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println("  ");
    }
}
```

La impresión en consola que recibo es:

```
[[I@4617c264    
[[I@4617c264  [[I@4617c264    
[[I@4617c264  [[I@4617c264  [[I@4617c264    
[[I@4617c264  [[I@4617c264  [[I@4617c264  [[I@4617c264    
[[I@4617c264  [[I@4617c264  [[I@4617c264  [[I@4617c264  [[I@4617c264
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > ¿Por que lo imprime así?

Por esta línea:

```java
System.out.print(calificaciones + "  ");
```

El identificador `calificaciones` es el nombre del **array bidimensional**.

Básicamente el código de arriba es equivalente a esto:

```java
System.out.print(calificaciones.toString() + "  ");
```

Esto quiere decir que en realidad estás invocando al método `toString` y esa es la razón del porque imprime caracteres extraños.

**¿Cómo compruebo si realmente se invoca el método toString de forma implícita?**

Simple, ejecutando este código de prueba:

```java
public class Program 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[][] calificaciones = new int[10][10];
        System.out.println(calificaciones  + " = " + calificaciones .toString());

    }
}
```

> > ¿Que debo hacer?

Solo necesitas usar la variable `calificacion`, ya que ahí es donde se tiene el valor de la celda:

```java
System.out.print(calificacion + "  ");
```

**¿Esos caracteres extraños que salen tienen algún significado?**

Sí.

Los tres primeros caracteres de esta impresión representa el nombre de la clase del objeto al que apunte `calificaciones`:

```java
--
 |
[[I  @4617c264
```

Una comprobación sencilla:

```java
public class Program 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[][] calificaciones = new int[10][10];
        System.out.println(calificaciones.getClass().getName());
    }

}
```

**Resultado por pantalla:**

```java
[[I
```

Los dos corchetes significa que la clase maneja un *array* bidimensional y la `I` quiere decir que el *array* almacena valores de tipo `int`.

Comment: Gracias!! Excelente!!

Answer (score 2):

el problema lo tienes cuando imprimes los datos del array bidimensional.
De la forma que lo tienes ahora te está imprimiendo objetos, más concretamente los arrays que llamas en el for cómo "calificaciones", tendrías que imprimir  calificación".

Te muestro el código modificado:

```
for(int[] CalificacionsPorAlumno : calificaciones) {
        for(int calificacion : CalificacionsPorAlumno) {
            System.out.print(calificacion + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("  ");
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! solucionado!!

Comment: @SandraBarrera No olvides de aceptar la respuesta que te sirvió.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Hola ! no se a que te refieres ! soy muy nueva en esto.. ¿Que debo hacer?

Comment: @SandraBarrera Por cada respuesta que tenga tu pregunta, hay una especie de visto grande color verde, ahí es donde debes darle clic a la respuesta que te sirvió o que te fue útil.

Comment: @MrDave1999 !Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! ha sido un día muy productivo en cuanto a aprendizaje..

Comment: @SandraBarrera De nada! Me da gusto que te haya servido las respuestas! Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En la línea `System.out.print(calificaciones + "  ");` estás imprimiendo una variable de tipo `int[] CalificacionsPorAlumno` por eso muestra la dirección en memoria de dicha variable. Para imprimir el valor dentro de esa dirección de memoria se puede usar `int calificacion`.

Es decir `System.out.print(calificacion + "  ");`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! solucionado !!

Comment: Lo que imprime no son direcciones de memoria. Simplemente es un **string** que retorna el método `toString`. Es decir, este código: `calificaciones + "  "` es equivalente a `calificaciones.toString() + "  "`

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma te imprime el array por pantalla.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int calificaciones[][]=new int [5][];
        calificaciones [0]=new int [1];
        calificaciones [1]=new int [2];
        calificaciones [2]=new int [3];
        calificaciones [3]=new int [4];
        calificaciones [4]=new int [5];


        for(int[] CalificacionsPorAlumno : calificaciones) 
        {
            for(int calificacion : CalificacionsPorAlumno) 
            {
                System.out.print(calificacion + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println("  ");
        }
    }
```

En el segundo for en el System.out.println estas llamando al objeto del array no a su valor.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!